# What restrictions exist choosing a MFC version to use with Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Each version of Visual Studio comes with a specific version of the MFC framework, but I believe MFC SDK can be downloaded separately. Since MFC is just C++, is there any reason you couldn't use the latest version with an older version of VC++... I don't mean trying to get the ribbon working in MSVC++ 6, But we're on VS2005 and some of the newer MFC features would be useful.

Comment: TTBOMK, the only way to get MFC is with a copy of VC++ (standard edition or above), which seems to render your question moot.

Comment: Did they change it? MS used to have a page _telling_ you how to get MFC working against VC++ Express, and surely the MFC feature-pack with the ribbon was made available separately? Would MS be _allowed_ to only make MFC available with their own compiler?

Comment: If you already have a copy of MFC (e.g., an older copy) you can use it with a newer compiler (including an express edition). He seems to want the reverse though: a new version of MFC to use with an older compiler. You can get the newer compiler without MFC, but I don't know of a way to get a newer copy of MFC without the compiler (legally anyway).

Comment: I can't find a link now on MSDN, maybe it was removed. But they definitely used to tell you how to set MFC up on Express editions, including downloading it. In fact here's a page on CodeProject about the same thing: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard about anyone using older versions of the compiler with new MFC's. I'm not even sure it would work out of the box, think e.g. about the for loop scoping changes in the previous VS version. I'd be very surprised about MS-sanctioned descriptions of getting MFC to work with VC Express - after all if they wanted people to do that, why wouldn't they just bundle MFC with VC Express?

Besides, cherry-picking MFC components was never really possible; over time, ATL and MFC CString were merged, they probably had to make changes in the rest of MFC/ATL to make that work.

My conclusion & opinion: very unlikely this will be easy to get to work.

Comment: I definitely remember a MSDN page that told you how to do it for VC++ Express 2005/8 9I forget which)m it was even linked from the Express page IIRC. I think it was either to download the Windows Platform SDK, or the DDK. I'm _sure_ it worked!

Comment: MFC was never in the SDK or the DDK, it has always been bundled only with VS. I'm not sure if you're talking about getting Express to use the MFC from an earlier VS that you had bought in full, but there was never a way to get MFC just from free downloads.

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused. All I can think is it was the bare Win32 SDK, since I can't find it I'll take your word for it. BUT, does this mean MS uses MFC to lock other compiler writers out of Windows development, as their proprietary technology?